# Facebook and Regular Login Conflict

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, omniauth

I have successfully integrated a facebook Login.  The problem is, when a user logs in through facebook, if they are not registered, it will create a user in the db for me.  This would be good but if they try to login later through regular methods (ie, my pages sign in) they wouldn't be able to - because they never actually created a password.

They also won't be able to create an account (with their facebook email) because I've saved that too.

After a couple days, and thanks to @magnum2002 's help, I would like to use a before_filter to check to see if they have a password.  The problem is, they have one EVEN if they logged in through facebook.  So an idea I had was to create a different column in my user db called "created_pw".  I use a hidden field on the form where the user actually created a password, and set it to true.  This way, if the user signed up through conventional methods, my DB will know that they created a password.  Then set the before_filter to see if THIS column is filled out. Testing this though, I saw that you can edit hidden fields in chromes developer tools.  Is there anyway to pass this information to my server without it actually being editable?

Then I will continue with Magnum's suggestion

```
user.rb
    def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource=nil)
    user = User.where(:provider => auth.provider, :uid => auth.uid).first
    if user
      return user
    else
      registered_user = User.where(:email => auth.info.email).first
      if registered_user
        return registered_user
      else
        user = User.create( 
                            name:auth.extra.raw_info.name,
                            provider:auth.provider,
                            uid:auth.uid,
                            email:auth.info.email,
                            password:Devise.friendly_token[0,20],
                          )
      end    
    end
end

end
```

Maybe I could do that in the callback...

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController   
  def facebook     
    @user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)      
    if @user.persisted?       
     sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
   end
 end
```

Here's my application controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 protect_from_forgery with: :exception
 def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    #if current_user haspassword_from_previous_registration?
   request.env['omniauth.origin'] || stored_location_for(resource) || root_path
    #else
      # request.env['omniauth.origin'] || stored_location_for(resource) ||  current_user_edit_path
  #end
 end
end
```

Would the commented code above in the application controller be the right idea?

Comment: create a filter in application controller that will take user to a page to put in a password, so he can not go to any page until he updates his account with a password

Comment: how would I do that? an if statement to differentiate between the devise friendly token and a user-set password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a `before_filter` in `application_controller` that will redirect user to `update_password` page if user has no password.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods/before_filter

also you'll need a `skip_before_filter` for the method where we'll display the form to update password.

example:

**application_controller.rb**

```
before_filter :redirect_if_no_password


def redirect_if_no_password
  redirect_to update_password_path if current_user.password.empty
end
```

**home_controller.rb**

```
skip_before_filter :redirect_if_no_password, only: :update_password

def update_password
end
```

you'll need also to skip this filter in actions that are not related to current user, like a visitor to your page that will opne Contact page or Feedback page.

Comment: But will the devise friendly token be accepted as a passowrd?

Comment: what you mean by devise friendly token ?

Comment: also you can do as CodeClimate does, you signup with github and after this they send you an email with a generated password that you can use to log in and also they advise you to changed it later in account settings.

Comment: when they log in with facebook, their password is saved as                             password:Devise.friendly_token[0,20].  If I redirect them to devises password update page on login, they won't know what that token is, could I add it as a hidden field maybe and then have them just add a new?

Comment: You can get this done they way I suggested or the way codeclimate does to generate a random password for them until they will update a new one

Comment: ok, so you generate a token using devise and send it to their email so they know that they have a password that they need to update after they log in, the same as codeclimate does

Comment: I got it with the filters, I like that approach more than the email.